# How would this horrible climate be possibly?

Tags: climate

I'm wondering if a pine forest with near-constant rain and thunder could be possible. I was thinking that possibly something like this could be created by high mountains next to [this place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catatumbo_lightning), lightning-wise, or somewhere on a tidally locked planet, but I don't know a lot about this topic. What geographical and other conditions might create a place like this?

Comment: Yes. See Washington state in the US. It is not clear what you are asking. What is the horrible climate exactly? Do you want constant lightning with mountains and a pine forest?

Comment: @jake the "rain side" of the Olympic Peninsula "only" receives an average of 160"/year, which is less than 1/2 inch per day.  Sure, that's a lot, but hardly "near-constant rain and thunder".

Comment: @RonJohn OP did not define "near constant". It is my fault for not explaining my comment, but in the US, near constant rain is compare to Washington state. And the link does not discuss rain fall that I can see. Truth be told though I am on my phone so I may not have full capability.

Comment: @jake I copied "*near-constant rain and thunder*" directly from the Question.

Comment: @RonJohn Okay and I didn't. What's your point?

Comment: @Jake Western Washington isn't rainy enough.  Of course, OP hasn't specified what he means by "near-constant rain", so maybe a near-constant drizzle is Good Enough.

Comment: @RonJohn I mean have you been to Seattle? I get what you mean though.

Comment: do you need a place on the planet or the entire planet, planet wide mono-climates are basically impossible.

Comment: Does it have to be constant, or would several hours every day suffice?  Around the Sierra Nevada, t's not at all uncommon for afternoon & evening thunderstorms to occur more often than not in the summer.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not according to Hard Science, but plausible enough for believability.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catatumbo_lightning

> The storms (and associated lightning) are likely the result of the winds blowing across the Maracaibo Lake and surrounding swampy plains. **These air masses inevitably meet the high mountain ridges** of the Andes, the Perijá Mountains (3,750 m), and Mérida's Cordillera, **enclosing the plain from three sides.**

That's a classic [Rain Shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_shadow).

Put that geographic scenario in the subtropics (mid-to-Northern Mexico through the Southern US), and you've got lots of rain, thunder and pine trees!

On a tidally locked planet, though?  Not plausible, because of the weather extremes created by one side being permanently sunny and *hot*, and the other side permanently dark.

Comment: you might want to explain what Catatumbo is, not everyone is going to know about the near constant lighting storm, cool as it is.